# How to edit the font in every row of a table in Word except for the first ones

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro in VBA which transfers data from Excel into a table inside of a Word document.

But because it's for work, the Document needs to meet special criteria when it comes to design. Because this is the first time I'm using VBA, I could use some help.

I have to change the font size and the font position but only for the rows I added. The already existing first two rows of the table are supposed to stay the same.

Does anyone have an idea?

This is the Excel Document

[image: This is the Excel Document]

This is what the Word document looks like after running the Code

[image: This is what the word document looks like after running the Code]

This is what its supposed to look like

[image: This is what its supposed to look like]

I tried to use the selection feature

```
With CurrentDoc    
  Dim myCells As Range
  Set myCells = .Range(Start:=.Tables(2).Cell(1, 3).Range.Start, End:=.Tables(2).Cell(4,3).Range.End)
  myCells.Select
        
  With Selection.Cells
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Name = "Roboto (Body)"
    .Font.Position = -18
  End With
End With
```

Comment: You could simply apply paragraph styles to the rows involved. Then you could simply modify the style. Styles are a core part of Word and ignoring them makes for much more work, and frustration. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `CurrentDoc` is the document containing the relevant Table and you want to do this on the second Table in that document:

```
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Set tbl = CurrentDoc.Tables(2)
Dim row As Long
For row = 3 To tbl.Rows.Count
    With tbl.Rows(row).Range.Font
        .Size = 10
        .Name = "Roboto (Body)"
        .Position = -18
    End With
Next row
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic is good. Setting font style all at once is more efficient. It is close to ready to go.

There is a merged cell in the 1st row, so `oTab.Columns.Count` doesn't work.

```vb
    Dim currentDoc, oTab As Table
    'Set currentDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oTab = currentDoc.Tables(2)
    Dim myCells As Range, rowCnt As Integer, colCnt As Integer
    rowCnt = oTab.Rows.Count
    colCnt = oTab.Rows(rowCnt).Cells.Count
    Set myCells = currentDoc.Range(Start:=oTab.Cell(3, 1).Range.Start, _
                    End:=oTab.Cell(rowCnt, colCnt).Range.End)
    With myCells
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Name = "Roboto (Body)"
        .Font.Position = -18
    End With
```

Comment: First Things first: Thank you very Much

Set myCells = currentDoc.Range(Start:=oTab.Cell(3, 1).Range.Start, _
                    End:=oTab.Cell(rowCnt, colCnt).Range.End)

I always get the Error Message 'Type Mismatch' referring to this line

Comment: I just noticed there is a merged cell in the 1st row. I have updated the code. It dynamically locate the last cell.